# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.voxmobili.sync.mapping.BMntMapping.checkVersion()Z

Tags: java

After I start Tomcat, I am getting following error message along with HTTP Status-500:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.voxmobili.sync.mapping.BMntMapping.checkVersion()Z
com.voxmobili.sync.srv.servlet.BServletSync.init(BServletSync.java:122)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve.invoke(RequestDumperValve.java:156)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) may be due to incompatible classes or incompatible jars at run time.

Answer (score 1):

This probably indicates that the jars or `.class` files you've put in `WEB-INF/lib` or `WEB-INF/classes` aren't a matching set: there is some sort of version skew. The error `NoSuchMethodError` indicates that some of your code is calling a method which was there at compile time but isn't present in the deployed version (or is present but has a different signature or return type).

Double check the versions of the jars you're deploying.